# Making a matrix with numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I tried to create a matrix using numpy.array with the following code

```py
def matrix_input(3):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(N):
        a = nd.array(input().split(),int)
        matrix.append(a)
    print(matrix)
```

But I'm getting the following output:
`[array([1, 1, 1]), array([1, 1]), array([1, 1, 1])]`

For the input:

```
1 1 1 
 1 1 
1 1 1
```

I don't want the matrix to have the word array in them... How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a list on the 4th line of your code. Also, correct your function as mentioned in the code below. **Function call** and **function creation** are two different things, so does the arguments you pass into it.

```
import numpy as np

def matrix_input(N):  # Argument to function while creation is wrong, use N instead of 3.
    matrix = []
    for i in range(N):
        a = list(np.array(input().split(),int))  # Make it a list here
        matrix.append(a)
    print(matrix)
```

output:

```
matrix_input(3)
1 1 1
1 1
1 1 1

[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Alternative method for creating a ***Proper matrix*** :

```
import numpy as np

matrix_1 = np.matrix([[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]])
print(matrix_1)
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 1]]
```

Comment: Is there an official stackoverflow recommendation to use `Python-3.x` over just `Python`. Do you have a link for me? I mean Python2 has been deprecated for over a year now. Can't we let it rest in peace?

Comment: @user2640045 i don't think there is one. But, i told that to OP because few people may still use python-2. Python-2 has reached end of life that was unknown to me.  I don't read that much of dev news. Sorry about that. In my OS however, Python-2 is still a default which is quite weird.